# Sharing content/DB between sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a public site and a basic, secured cms'y site. They will be on the same host. I want to use the same DB (writing from the cms, reading from public), **and** have access to the same content (filesystem) so I can upload images (not sql blobs) to the public site from the cms site.

What is the best way to do this? Is it via some permission setup in my web.config?

I'd do it as a single site with areas or namespaces, but i'm using WebAPI where it's not really supported (yes you can do it but the pitfalls soon become apparent).

Comment: It has nothing to do with permissions, you just write another ConnectionString to web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a long answer and a short answer to this question.

**The short answer:**

- Database Access would be controlled in the web.config of the relevant site(s). Multiple sites can easily talk to the same database, as can multiple instances of a site (web farm).
- Filesystem access would be controlled at the IIS level. You can assign access to the filesystem by granting the user running the site permissions to directories, locations, and files.

**The long answer**

The reason there is a long answer is that there are multiple options here and it all depends on how you are setting up your stack. So you want to set up 2 sites that manage the same data from 2 different perspectives? Here are a couple of options off the top of my head:

**One**

I would say the easiest way would be to have a solution that has 2 web projects in it. The benefits:

- 2 websites that do different things as part of one solution - makes logical sense as well as technical sense.
- Then they could be deployed as separate sites in IIS, so would be easy to manage as separate urls or as subdomains of one url.
- They could share a common dll that essentially handles the application, or they could simply be 2 different versions

**Two**

If you are using Web API, why not have functionality for both sites built into the API, then set access levels on the API to restrict the activities a particular site can do (i.e. manage content vs read content). Some benefits:

- Same codebase used by both sites makes it easier to organise your business logic.
- Restriction to certain functionality could be done by token or incoming IP range or a host of other options.

**Three**

Is there any reason you have to separate the functionality? Based on the user logged in, you could easily have a dynamic menu, and security that simply changes the functions a user is allowed to access. (or, as your post suggests, one set of 'view' functionality for unauthenticated users, and one set for authenticated).

- Easy deployment profile
- Single development code base
- common - This would be the profile for many blog frameworks (e.g. Orchard) A user is in view mode if not logged in - i.e. any blog reader - but the admin/owner can log in to get to the blog / cms functionality.